# ImageSwitcher took several seconds when Grow heap happen (already down scale)

Tags: java, android, performance

I've already read a lot of posts,still can't solve it.
I have an app that have one problem related to OOM. It can show a picture stored(PNG type,approximately 1.33MB, 3072*1728 pixel) on server. My system heap size is 125MB
get by: `long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();`

I new a thread( AsyncTask )to decode it by using new a handle to manage it.
I also down scale the picture when it is too big. Image can show in local device.

But, it still happen **Grow heap (frag case) to 10.389MB for 2654224-byte allocation** 
And, it will take 2~10 sec to collect the garbage.
It's bad user experience. Did any one meet the same problem? Any Suggestion?

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    public static String TAG = "DownloadImageTask";
    public enum DOWNLOAD_STATE {
        eIdle, eProgressing, eError, eSuccess,
    }
    private DOWNLOAD_STATE state = DOWNLOAD_STATE.eIdle;
    private Bitmap dlBitmap;

    public DownloadImageTask(String imageUrl) {
        execute(imageUrl);
    }

    public DOWNLOAD_STATE getDownloadState() {
        return state;
    }

    public Bitmap getDownloadBitmap() {
        return dlBitmap;
    }

    public Drawable getDownloadDrawable() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Drawable dlDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(dlBitmap);
        return dlDrawable;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        try {
            dlBitmap = getBitmap(urldisplay);
        }
        if(dlBitmap==null)
            state = DOWNLOAD_STATE.eError;
        else
            state = DOWNLOAD_STATE.eSuccess;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        dlBitmap = null;
        state = DOWNLOAD_STATE.eError;
    }

    return dlBitmap;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    result = null;
}



public Bitmap getBitmap(String urldisplay) {


    try {
        Log.d(TAG,"getBitmap File");
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        if(in == null)
            Log.d(TAG,"in null");
        // first decode, get the length & width of picture,didn't load the picture into memory

        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, opts);
        //in.close();


        //compute the SampleSize (power of 2 is great)
        int sampleSize = computeSampleSize(opts, -1, 1920 * 1080);//monitor limitation
        Log.d(TAG,"samplesize ="+sampleSize);
        // second decode,set sample size , generate thumbnail
        in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        opts.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
        opts.inInputShareable = true;
        opts.inPurgeable = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, opts);
        in.close();
        return bmp;
    } catch (Exception err) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + err.toString());
        return null;
    }
}

public static int computeSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int minSideLength, int maxNumOfPixels) {

    Log.d(TAG,"computeSampleSize");
    int initialSize = computeInitialSampleSize(options, minSideLength,
            maxNumOfPixels);
    int roundedSize;

    if (initialSize <= 8) {
        roundedSize = 1;
        while (roundedSize < initialSize) {
            roundedSize <<= 1;
        }
    } else {
        roundedSize = (initialSize + 7) / 8 * 8;
    }

    return roundedSize;
}

private static int computeInitialSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int minSideLength, int maxNumOfPixels) {

    Log.d(TAG,"computeInitialSampleSize");
    try{
        double w = options.outWidth;
        double h = options.outHeight;

        int lowerBound = (maxNumOfPixels == -1) ? 1 : (int) Math.ceil(Math
                .sqrt(w * h / maxNumOfPixels));
        int upperBound = (minSideLength == -1) ? 128 : (int) Math.min(
                Math.floor(w / minSideLength), Math.floor(h / minSideLength));

        if (upperBound < lowerBound) {
            // return the larger one when there is no overlapping zone.
            return lowerBound;
        }

        if ((maxNumOfPixels == -1) && (minSideLength == -1)) {
            return 1;
        } else if (minSideLength == -1) {
            return lowerBound;
        } else {
            return upperBound;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,"computeInitialSampleSize err:"+e.toString());
        return 1;
    }

}
}
```

And, show the picture in ImageSwitcher

```
myImageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(task.getDownloadDrawable());
```